# Common Lisp scoping (dynamic vs lexical)

Tags: dynamic, lisp, common-lisp, scoping, lexical

EDIT: I changed the example code after the first answer because I came up with a simple version that begs the same questions.

I am currently learning Common Lisp's scoping properties. After I thought I had a solid understanding I decided to code up some examples that I could predict the outcome of, but apparently I was wrong. I have three question, each one relating to an example below:

Example 1:

```
(defmethod fun1 (x)
  (print x)
  (fun2))

(defmethod fun2 ()
  (print x))

(fun1 5)
```

Output:

```
5 
*** - EVAL: variable X has no value
```

Question: This makes sense. x is statically scoped and fun2 has no way of finding the value of x without having it passed explicitly.

Example 2:

```
(defvar x 100)

(defmethod fun1 (x)
  (print x)
  (fun2))

(defmethod fun2 ()
  (print x))

(fun1 5)
```

Output:

```
5
5
```

Question: I don't understand why x is suddenly visible to fun2 with the value that fun1 gave it, instead of having a value of 100...

Example 3:

```
(setf x 100)

(defmethod fun1 (x)
  (print x)
  (fun2))

(defmethod fun2 ()
  (print x))

(fun1 5)
```

Output:

```
5
100
```

Question: Should I ignore these results since calling setf on an undeclared variable is apparently undefined? This happens to be what I would expect in my second example...

Any insight would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Here is my naive explanation after playing around a little bit... let me know if I'm close..

Exmaple 1: needs no explanation

Example 2: declaring x as a dynamic variable causes all instances of x to be looked up at run time on the dynamic variable stack, which would cause fun2 to inherit x's value from fun1, despite not being a dynamic variable.

Example3:
no idea...I guess its undefined

Comment: *Raising* questions is good. *Begging* questions is **bad.**

Comment: Instead of DEFMETHOD use DEFUN. A DEFMETHOD is not needed in these examples. DEFUN creates a simple function. DEFMETHOD is for generic functions, where you need some dispatching.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The effects of setting an undefined variable using `setf` is undefined in ANSI Common Lisp.

`defvar` will define a *special variable*. This declaration is global and also has effect on `let` bindings. That's the reason that by convention these variables are written as `*foo*`. If you have ever defined `x` with `defvar`, it is declared *special* and there is **no** way to declare it *lexical* later.

`let` by default provides local lexical variables. If the variable was already declared special (for example because of a `defvar`), then it just creates a new local dynamic binding.

**Update**

- Example 1 .

Nothing to see.

- Example 2

`x` has been declared special. All uses of the variable `x` now use dynamic binding.
When calling the function, you bind `x` to `5`. Dynamically. Other functions can now access this dynamic binding and get that value.

- Example 3

This is *undefined* behavior in Common Lisp. You are setting an undeclared variable. What happens then is implementation dependent. Your implementation (most do something similar) sets the *symbol value* of `x` to `100`. In `fun1`, `x` is lexically bound. In `fun2` evaluating `x` retrieves the symbol value (or possibly to the dynamically bound value) of `x`.

As an example for an implementation that did (does?) something else: the CMUCL implementation would also have declare `x` in example 3 by default to be special. Setting an undefined variable also declares it special.

**NOTE**

In portable standard compliant Common Lisp code the global variables are defined with `defvar` and `defparameter`. Both declare these variables to be special. ALL uses of these variables now involve dynamic binding.

Remember:

```
((lambda (x)
   (sin x))
 10)
```

is basically the same as

```
(let ((x 10))
  (sin x))
```

Which means that variable bindings in `let` bindings and variable bindings in function calls are working the same way. If `x` would have been declared special in some place earlier, both would involve dynamic binding.

This is specified in the Common Lisp standard. See for example the explanation to the [SPECIAL declaration](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_specia.htm#special).

Comment: I've updated my original post with more precise examples and questions that reflect what I was having trouble understanding. Specifically, the behavior demonstrated in my second example when compared with my first example

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I don't think I was expecting the parameter values of functions to be effected the same way as normal free variables... but I suppose every mention is treated the same.

Comment: @antman8969: variable usage is the same everywhere. What is a little surprising is that function parameters can also be dynamically bound and that they are affected by the definition of variables with DEFVAR.