# Subtlety about Common Lisp scoping (dynamic vs lexical)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, scoping, lexical-scope, dynamic-scope

After reading documentation about the declaration [SPECIAL](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_specia.htm#special), the special operator [LET](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm), the macro [DEFVAR](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm), and several questions here at StackOverflow about the dynamic versus lexical scoping in Common Lisp, as, for instance, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787683/common-lisp-scoping-dynamic-vs-lexical), I still can't understand the following behaviour after evaluating these forms in SBCL.

```
;; x is a free variable
CL-USER> (defun fn ()
           (print x))
; in: DEFUN FN
;     (PRINT X)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: X
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     X
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
FN

CL-USER> (describe 'x)
COMMON-LISP-USER::X
  [symbol]
; No value

CL-USER> (let ((x 'dinamic_1st_binding))
           (declare (special x))
           (print x)
           (fn)
           (let ((x 'dinamic_2nd_binding))
             (declare (special x))
             (print x)
             (fn))
           (let ((x 'lexical_1st_binding))
             (print x)
             (fn))
           (values))

DINAMIC_1ST_BINDING 
DINAMIC_1ST_BINDING 
DINAMIC_2ND_BINDING 
DINAMIC_2ND_BINDING 
LEXICAL_1ST_BINDING 
DINAMIC_1ST_BINDING 
; No value

;; x is defvar'ed as a top level form
CL-USER> (defvar x 'dinamic_global_binding)
X

CL-USER> (describe 'x)
COMMON-LISP-USER::X
  [symbol]

X names a special variable:
  Value: DINAMIC_GLOBAL_BINDING
; No value

CL-USER> (let ((x 'dinamic_1st_binding))
           (declare (special x))
           (print x)
           (fn)
           (let ((x 'dinamic_2nd_binding))
             (declare (special x))
             (print x)
             (fn))
           (let ((x 'lexical_1st_binding))
             (print x)
             (fn))
           (values))

DINAMIC_1ST_BINDING 
DINAMIC_1ST_BINDING 
DINAMIC_2ND_BINDING 
DINAMIC_2ND_BINDING 
LEXICAL_1ST_BINDING 
LEXICAL_1ST_BINDING 
; No value
```

Why does the third call to `fn`, before the variable `x` is defvar'ed, prints `DINAMIC_1ST_BINDING` and after the variable `x` is defvar'ed it prints `LEXICAL_1ST_BINDING`?

Comment: you have repeatedly created tag wikis that plagiarize text from another source.  If you are going to create tag wikis, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits#suggested-edits/2690825?&_suid=13760758282670037369063379608436) that takes verbatim from [here](http://alouche.net/2011/01/21/fdp-foundry-discovery-protocol/), **please include a link to the source in your entry**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's go step-by-step.

### Form 1

```
(defun fn ()
  (print x))
```

This defines `fn`.

Since the referenced `x` variable is not declared lexically, we get a warning.

Free referenced variables are usually **locally** assumed `special` with a free declaration<sup>1</sup>. This is not defined in the standard, but most implementations do it and signal a warning.

The same principle applies to evaluating the top-level form `(setq x ...)` in a file or in a REPL.

None of these situations are supposed to **globally** declare `x` as `special`.

### Form 2

```
(describe 'x)
```

`x` is just a symbol. Nothing happened to it **globally**.

### Form 3

```
(let ((x 'dinamic_1st_binding))
  (declare (special x))
  (print x)
  (fn)
  (let ((x 'dinamic_2nd_binding))
    (declare (special x))
    (print x)
    (fn))
  (let ((x 'lexical_1st_binding))
    (print x)
    (fn))
  (values))
```

The first binding to `x` is **locally** declared `special`. So, `fn` will pick it up.

The second binging to `x` is more of the same, just creating a new dynamic binding for `x`, which is unwound after the call to `fn`.

The third binding to `x` is a lexical binding, because every binding is lexical unless there's a **global** `special` declaration or a **local** `special` bound declaration<sup>1</sup> for the bound variable.

Thus, `fn`, which picks up the most recent dynamic binding of `x`, will pick up `dinamic_1st_binding`.

The `x`s in the `print` forms use whatever enclosing meaning of `x`, thus picking the `special` `x` when it's declared special and the lexical `x` when not.

### Form 4

```
(defvar x 'dinamic_global_binding)
```

This **globally** declares `x` as `special` and sets its `symbol-value` to `dinamic_global_binding`.

Every use of the symbol `x` as a variable is now tainted with this **global** `special` declaration. From this point on, there is no standard way for code to either bind or refer to a variable named `x` as a lexical variable.

### Form 5

```
(describe 'x)
```

We now observe the side effects of the previous form. `x` is **globally** special, and its current dynamic value is `dinamic_global_binding`.

### Form 6

```
(let ((x 'dinamic_1st_binding))
  (declare (special x))
  (print x)
  (fn)
  (let ((x 'dinamic_2nd_binding))
    (declare (special x))
    (print x)
    (fn))
  (let ((x 'lexical_1st_binding))
    (print x)
    (fn))
  (values))
```

All bindings of `x` are special. ∎

---

1. A declaration is *bound* if it gives meaning to the establishment of a binding in the form that performs the binding, and is *free* otherwise, i.e. if it gives meaning only to references/uses of a binding.

So, the following example:

```
(defun fn2 ()
  (print y))

(let ((y 1))
  (fn2)
  (locally (declare (special y))
    (fn2)))
```

does not make `let` bind `y` dynamically. It only makes the code lexically under `locally` that refers to `y` treat it as a dynamic variable through a *free* declaration. In this case, both calls to `fn2` will signal an error.

The following:

```
(let ((y 1))
  (declare (special y))
  (print y)
  (let ((y 2))
    (print y)
    (locally (declare (special y))
      (print y))
    (print y)))
```

will print:

```
1
2
1
2
```

The first binding of `y` has a *bound* `special` declaration, so it's a dynamic binding.

The second binding of `y` has no *bound* `special` declaration and `y` is not **globally** `special`, so it's a lexical binding.

Thus, the access to `y` is also conditioned by (missing) declarations about `y`.

The second declaration is a *free* declaration, making references to the variable `y` be treated as dynamic. So, the immediatlely previous binding to a variable named `y` is not changed by this *free* declaration.

The following example:

```
(let ((y 1))
  (print y)
  (locally (declare (special y))
    (print y)))
```

will fail in the second `print` form, because its reference to `y` is dynamic and there is no established dynamic binding for `y`, i.e. `y` is unbound and an `unbound-variable` error is signaled.

Answer (score 2):

In case one there is a lexical binding of x.

In case two there is no lexical binding. It's just that you have the symbol, but that's misleading, since it clearly shows that the last x is dynamically bound, too.

Answer (score 2):

`Defvar` *et al.* proclaim the variable to be *globally special*.  That means that every binding of this variable is dynamic, even if you omit `special` declarations.

In your second run, binding `x` to `'lexical-1st-binding` is misleading, because it is a dynamic binding anyway.