# Dynamic Binding in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

This question is an extension of [Common Lisp scoping (dynamic vs lexical)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787683/common-lisp-scoping-dynamic-vs-lexical)

I have read and (hopefully) understood the concepts of scoping and extent in Common Lisp (link: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node43.html), but I am unable to get my head around the following three examples. All examples are run on a fresh lisp session in SBCL/Slime/Emacs.

Example 1: Prints 5 & 5

```
(defvar x 100)
(defun fun1 (x)
   (print x)
   (fun2))

(defun fun2 ()
   (print x))
     
(fun1 5)
```

Example 2: Prints 5 & 100

```
 (defun fun1 (x)
   (print x)
   (fun2))

 (defun fun2 ()
   (print x))
    
 (defvar x 100)
 
 (fun1 5)
```

Example 3: Prints 5 & 5 & 100

```
(defvar x 100)

(defun fun1 (x)
  (print x)
  (fun2))

(defun fun2 ()
  (print x))

(defvar x 100)
     
(fun1 5)

x
```

I understand why **fun1** always prints 5 (due to lexical scope, but please correct if I'm wrong). What I don't understand is why **fun2** prints 5 in Example 1, 100 in Example 2 and again 5 in Example 3?

- Example 1: x, a variable with indefinite scope, is set to 5 in **fun1** and accordingly **fun2** access this value. Is this a correct interpretation?
- Example 2: x is set to 100 by **defvar**, but why is not being re-set to 5 when **fun1** is called? I thought the bindings took place when the functions are called or is it when they are defined? It appears that x is not yet bound when fun1 is defined, and therefore the binding of x in fun1 (which is lexically scoped) is not seen by the rest of the program and then the "global" binding takes place with the subsequent **defvar**. Is the behaviour x in the function call then due to lexical shadowing in **fun1** but no dynamic shadowing for **fun2**? I.e. there are two different instances of x here since fun1 defined its x first and did not see a "global" x at the time.
- Example 3: It appears here that since x is set globally first, both fun1 and fun2 are referencing the same instance of x and hence its value is updated during fun1 and applied also during fun2 (both are 5)? Furthermore I get 100 when I ask for the value of x at the end (why? when fun2 is returning 5?)

It has something to do with the following extract from Guy Steel's Common Lisp book, but I cannot get my head around it:

> "Constructs that use lexical scope effectively generate a new name for
> each established entity on each execution. Therefore dynamic shadowing
> cannot occur (though lexical shadowing may). This is of particular
> importance when dynamic extent is involved."

Is the following statement always true (source: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs421/sp2010/lectures/dynamicscope.pdf):

> The binding rule in Lisp is this: a use of a name is bound to the most
> recent declaration of that name that is still live.

I'm starting to understand some of the parts, but cannot get a wholistic understanding of all three parts, so it would be very helpful if you could help.

Comment: Notice that 'returns' is probably the wrong word. You mean 'prints'. 'returning' means in the functional paradigm the return value of an expression.

Comment: Many thanks Rainer, I have updated this

Comment: I think it's really important to note that Example 2's behaviour is *undefined* in CL: a reference to a free variable from a function where there is both no apparent special declaration nor any visible lexical binding of that variable at the time the function is defined is undefined behaviour.  Rainer Joswig's answer points this out explicitly.

Comment: @tfb Thanks, you are very correct. His and Sylwester's answer touch upon this quite well. That said, the answer I accepted helped me the most in understanding the concepts as it stepped through a bit more slowly through the ideas of scope and extent. Ideally, we should add the notes you just mentioned to the accepted answer, but I am very much a beginner on Stack Overflow, so not sure what is the correct way and etiquette

Comment: @AshokKhanna: I think the accepted answer is fine, and since Rainer's answer (which won't go away, unlike comments) mentions it everything is fine.  I just wanted to be sure that you hadn't missed the slightly subtle issue, really.

Comment: @tfb Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Example 1: x, a variable with indefinite scope, is set to 5 in fun1 and accordingly fun2 access this value. Is this a correct interpretation?

Mostly, let me expand on that.

When `x` is declared by `defvar`, the variable is being declared as special, and from now on `x` is *always* seen as a special variable, and bound dynamically. When you call:

```
(fun1 5)
```

The binding in `fun1` is done dynamically, meaning both the return value of `fun1` and `fun2` are based on the current dynamic binding of `x`.

> Example 2:  [...] I.e. there are two different instances of x here since fun1 defined its x first and did not see a "global" x at the time.

Yes, but this is not true in all interpreters (see Sylwester's answer). When you define `fun1`, `x` is not known to be special; that means the scope at this point for parameter `x` is lexical. Later, when `defvar` is evaluated, the binding of `x` in `fun1` is still lexical, and as such calling `fun1` does not modify the dynamic binding of global variable `x`.

> Example 3: [...] Furthermore I get 100 when I ask for the value of x at the end (why? when fun2 is returning 5?

Special variable have *indefinite scope*, they are visible everywhere, but their bindings has *dynamic extent*, which means a binding lives only as long as the form that establishes it.

Here, when you ask for `x` at the toplevel, you have the value that is globally bound to `x`, 100; the value of 5 is only temporarily bound to `x` while the call to `fun1` is in effect.

If you used `SETF` to mutate a binding, then you could mutate the global binding, but this is not what happens during function application or `let` bindings.

Comment: Many thanks! Both of your answers are excellent, I wish I could make them both the answer. My final qn - would you be able to elaborate on Ex. 3 a bit more? I can see that fun1 sets the value of x to 5, which expires when fun1 ends. Does fun2 get the value of 5 because the binding of fun1 is still "live"? I can see if I call fun2 separately, it returns 100 so that seems to be the case. Would you be able to help expand on the quote in my question that refers to dynamic shadowing vs. lexical shadowing and tying it back to your answer as I'm unable to find materials online on shadowing for lisp?

Answer (score 5):

Some annotations to your code:

**Example 1**

```
(defvar x 100)    ; declares X to be special, globally and locally
                  ; also sets X to 100

(defun fun1 (x)   ; X is a dynamically bound variable
  (print x)       ; lookup of dynamic binding of X
  (fun2))        

(defun fun2 ()
  (print x))      ; lookup of dynamic binding of X
     
(fun1 5)
```

**Example 2**

```
 (defun fun1 (x)  ; X is a lexical local variable
   (print x)      ; lexical reference to X
   (fun2))

 (defun fun2 ()
   (print x))     ; X is undeclared/undefined
                  ; the exact behaviour is undefined in Common Lisp
                  ; many implementations assume dynamic lookup of X
                  ; most compilers will show a warning
                  ; CMUCL also by default declared X globally to be special
                  ; -> don't use this in your code
    
 (defvar x 100)   ; declares X to be special, globally and locally 
                  ; also sets X to 100     
 (fun1 5)
```

**Example 3**

```
(defvar x 100)    ; declares X to be special, globally and locally
                  ; also sets X to 100

(defun fun1 (x)   ; X is a dynamically bound variable
  (print x)       ; lookup of dynamic binding of X
  (fun2))

(defun fun2 ()
  (print x))      ; lookup of dynamic binding of X

(defvar x 100)    ; does nothing
                  ;  -> X is already declared special
                  ;  -> X already has a value
                  ;     see also: DEFPARAMETER
     
(fun1 5)

x                 ; lookup of global (or thread local) value of X
```

Comment: Many thanks for this and also for your help on the original question that I was learning from that lead to this question

Answer (score 3):

Your trick works differently in different implementations. Eg. in CLISP, which doesn't compile their functions on the fly, will behave the exact same in the two first examples and exactly the same as your output if you compile the functions as you go.

Dynamic scope means lexical scope doesn't apply:

```
(defparameter *test* 100)

(defun print-test ()
  (print *test*))

(defun call-print-test-with (*test*)
  (print-test))

(print-test)         ; prints 100
(call-print-test 10) ; prints 10
```

Because `*test*` is dynamic (global) changing a local variable with the same name temporarily overwrites it until the scope that overwrites it is gone. This is what dynamic means.

If `*test*` was lexically scoped both would print `100`.

This is why you should always use `*earmuffs*` on globals. If you have defined a variable somewhere with `defvar` or `defparameter` using the same as a parameter or local variable somewhere you might change the variable temporarily without knowing and it might be very hard to find where it happens! When people see `*earmuffs*` in parameters and `let` they understand this is the intent. eg.

```
(with-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
  (some-function-whose-printed-output-you-want))
; ==> a string with the actual output
```

The function which is called is non the wiser. It thinks it is printing to stdout but you have wrapped it and changed the output stream during its execution.

Comment: Many thanks! Both of your answers are excellent, I wish I could make them both the answer. My Qn - why do different implementations perform differently - does that mean the ANSI Common Lisp standard has not set this in stone, or perhaps some implementations are non-compliant on this?

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify my comment above - is there a reason why is there no standard way for handling Example 2 (where the "x" in fun1 is kept seperate to the other x), is it because the standard is not clear on this or due to nonconformance of some interpreters?

Comment: @AshokKhanna When you define a function that uses a variable not created in the function itself it assumes it's special, however a variable you do create can be declared special. If you do that there will be no more ambiguity and the place of the `defvar` is no longer important and doesn't even need to be defined top level. Under-specifying leaves room for interpretation and most lisp systems jut use the information they got and run with it. SBCL is very verbose about it's assumptions when you enter your code. Usually you should not see any output for it to be unambiguous.